# android NavController does not handle fast back press with animation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, android-lifecycle, android-architecture-navigation

When using fragment transition animation using navigation components, the exit fragment (A) onDestroyView is not called until animation completes. If during that time i press the BACK button the UI transaction not seem to be handled correctly by the `NavController`. A fragment (to which i returned) turns white, if i press HOME and then return to the app i see fragment B with fragment A toolbar and the UI non responsive, if during that state i navigate using the hamburger, i see fragment B at the background.

Similar when i transition from B to C and fast back to B.

ps: it does not matter if i use BACK or UP button.

I seen some references talking about detach issue of `NavHostFragment` but nothing conclusive

I went over codelabs tutorial (very good BTW) and the google documentation but could not find any error in my code.

MainActivity

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val binding: MainActivityBinding  = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(
        this,
        R.layout.main_activity
    )

    val host: NavHostFragment = supportFragmentManager
        .findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment? ?: return

    navController = host.navController

    val navHeader: NavHeaderBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
        layoutInflater,
        R.layout.nav_header,
        binding.navView,
        false
    )

    binding.navView.addHeaderView(navHeader.root)

    setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)

    //first variable is the destinations to show the hamburger icon and the other is the drawer
    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        setOf(R.id.main_dest),
        binding.drawerLayout
    )

    val menuConnect = binding.navView.menu.findItem(R.id.connect)

    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfig)

    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

    binding.lifecycleOwner = this
}
```

main_activity.xml

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.glist.MainActivity"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/Base.Theme.Toolbar"
            app:subtitleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.Subtitle"/>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_drawer_menu" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Gradle

```
ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.10"
ext.navigationVersion = "2.3.2"

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.1'

// KTX
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'

// Navigation
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigationVersion"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigationVersion"

//ViewModel
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0'

// Hilt
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"
implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha02'
kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha02'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.5.0'
```

Comment: Navigation doesn't control fragment animations - that would be dependent on what version of Fragments you are using. What version are you using / have you tried upgrading to the latest version?

Comment: navigation-fragment-ktx & navigation-ui-ktx are 2.3.2. I implemented most of the navigation code from codelabs but it does not happen their, even if i upgrade to latest versions their as well. I tried comparing the codelabs, it is a bit old but i think most is the same (hard to be sure). I have a feeling i am close to the solution, i will try more tomorrow. If you have any idea please let me know.

Comment: That's the version of *Navigation*. I was asking about the version of *Fragments*. Those are different things. Maybe include your `dependencies` block from your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: Added gradle. The codelabs tutorial did not include fragment dependency so i didn't as well. I tried to add in addition with different versions (including the latest) but it didn't seem to help

Comment: There's no known issues like this with the stable version of Fragments, but there's been a lot of improvements in the current Fragment 1.3.0-beta02 version in this space which might fix your issue. If you're still seeing issues after switching to that version of Fragments, I'd strongly suggest [filing a bug against Fragments](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=460964) with a sample project that reproduces your issue.

Comment: Problem solved by adding the 1.3.0-beta02 implementation! I just couldn't believe it since i am working on this issue for days. Just to be sure, i removed the implementation and could easily reproduce the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by adding the Fragment implementation with `1.3.0-beta02` versions in addition to navigation implementations

```
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.0-beta02"
```

That seems as recent fix since trying 1.3.0-beta01 still has the issue

As noted by @ianhanniballake, that is the fragment responsibility.

I had the Fragment implementation before in addition to the `navigation-fragment-ktx`, but from a different version.

BTW - Funny thing that the android compiles even without the Fragment implementation so i figured it is inside the `navigation-fragment-ktx` or something so focused on its versions. I am not sure, but i think the codelabs does not include the Fragment implementation, at least i didn't see it in my result project. Perhaps should be noted in google docs.

If any issue with my answer please let me know and don't be hurry to downgrade.

[Edit]
1.3.0-beta02 still has some issue with transition (animation?) but that is a lot harder to replicate. I could easily do it in 1.3.0-beta02 and tested for about 10 minutes while also going back and forward with versions to confirm and could not see the issue. but through continuing to play, one time the previous fragment was under the current one until exiting the app. Since that is still beta, i guess they will solve it eventually. I will file a bug as @ianhanniballake recommended